# how to load "NEXT_PUBLIC" env variables from AWS ELB

Tags: environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, next.js

how to load "NEXT_PUBLIC" env variables from AWS ELB ?

I deployed my project to AWS ELB and set the env variables in settings.

other env Key has loaded like this "process.env.SOMETHING"

but env Key name starts with "NEXT_PUBLIC" cannot loaded in Next.js client side.

I'd appreciate it if you could solve it

Comment: Hi, you need to rebuild your app everytime you change a NEXT_PUBLIC variable. This is because they are injected in client-code at build-time and cannot change afterward, contrary to what you are used to on the server. Btw this is probably not related to AWS ELB.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution! i have one more question. if using code-pipeline with github, and [.env] file included in  [.gitignore]. then how can I use  PUBLIC variables in my production? should i not ignore them?

Comment: I use 2 files: `.env.production` is tracked by git, `.env.production.local` is not. This way I can put the default, public,  non-secret variables in `.env.production` and I keep the private one into the ignored `.env.production.local`. On  your GitHub actions, you can define the secret variables directly in the pipeline.

Comment: @EricBurel you are genius. thanks a lot. i will try it tomorrow